# Eloquent delete and MySQL foreign key cascade

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, relationship, dingo-api

I have these tables in MySQL database:

users['id', 'name'],

roles['id', 'title'] and

user_role ['user_id', 'role_id'] where both are foreign keys, CASCADE.

---

When it catches an exception the user remains in the table as wanted, while the row from the relation table is deleted.

```
try{
    $user->delete();
}
catch (\Exception $e){
    throw new \Dingo\Api\Exception\DeleteResourceFailedException('Error.');
}
```

Is this eloquent's mistake?

---

Now, I figured out a way to fix this but I'm not sure that it's the best practise. Is there a better way to do it?

```
try{
    $roleId = $user->roles[0]->id;
    $user->delete();
}
catch (\Exception $e){
    $user->roles()->attach($roleId);
    throw new \Dingo\Api\Exception\DeleteResourceFailedException('Error.');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understood your question, transactions are what you need.

[Database Transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database#database-transactions)

```
DB::transaction(function () {
    $user->delete();
});
```

and in case you face a deadlock use this one

```
 DB::transaction(function () {
    $user->delete();
},5);
```

Comment: Yes that did the trick. I still had to wrap it with a try catch, trough. Many thanks!